# How to add the local Library to product flavour in gradle latest version 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a library in libs folder.I need to add that library to specific product flavour. previously we have **Compile** but latest version it is deprecated and added "**API**"

**Previously:**

```
dependencies {
....
market1Compile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'market1Release')
market2Compile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'market2Release')
```

}

**Now:**

```
api files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v2.3.1.17.jar')
```

How add that to particular flavor. any one help me!!

Comment: Please see ["Publish dependencies"](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#publishing_deps) section.

Answer (score -1):

Put your local library inside the dependencies.
Like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('your_library.jar')
}
```

Comment: Pls check the question properly. i need to add for updated gradle version